# Vue Router doesn't update page when named variable is manually changed

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have the following definition in my Vue router

```json
{
    path: '/search/entity/:entity',
    name: PageType.SEARCH_RESULTS_ENTITY_ID,
    component: Entity
}
```

If a user types in `id3` into a search box, they end up at `/#/search/entity/id3` either shows the data or a "Not Found" exception.

The challenge I'm facing is that if one of my users manually changes the URL to `/#/search/entity/id4` the page stays on `3` and doesn't update to `4`'s content. The only way to get that to happen is with a full page refresh.

I tried this hack

```
window.addEventListener("hashchange", (e: HashChangeEvent) => {
    router.push({
        path: window.location.hash.substr(1),
    });
})
```

but it gives this error:

> NavigationDuplicated: Avoided redundant navigation to current location: "/search/entity/id4

How can I get Vue to detect and update the page when these changes happen? Note that I have this schema on a large number of pages, so I'm looking for a global project solution.

Comment: If vue-router doesn't need to serve a completely different component, it's going to reuse the same one and not perform a full page reload for efficiency. It's on the component to update itself based on route params changing.  You can do that with a [watcher](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#reacting-to-params-changes)

Comment: @yoduh I would have to duplicate that code in over a dozen places. That's what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: perhaps a `beforeRouteUpdate` [navigation guard](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards) would work instead

Comment: @yoduh that's still a per-component solution.

Comment: Technically yes, but at least it'd all be in the same file (router.js).  Maybe you can [key](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-special-attributes.html) on route params on an element in your root component (App.vue) or other shared parent component?  Other than that I'm out of ideas. Sorry

Comment: Am I missing something. The examples you linked to are labeled as `In-Component Guards`. I'm not seeing a way to add them to `router.js` like you can do for things like `beforeEnter`.